# Keypress event listener not working in Mozilla SDK

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm using Addon SDK 1.17 and Firefox 33.

I'm trying to implement something similar to [aardvark](http://karmatics.com/aardvark/) in an addon.

In my content script I have this, to set things up:

```
self.on('message', function onMessage(activation, totarget) {
  document.addEventListener("click", onMouseClick, true);
  document.addEventListener("keypress", onKeyPress, true);
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove, true);
});
```

And the onKeyPress function is this, so far:

```
function onKeyPress(event) {
  console.log('key pressed');
}
```

I've tried putting the above into a normal html page:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      function onKeyPress(event) {
        console.log('key pressed')
      }
      document.addEventListener("keypress", onKeyPress, true);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the console merrily logs my keypresses away.

I can't see why this not working in my addon, as the other mouse and click events are working just fine.

I've tried attaching the listeners to `window` instead, and listening for `keydown`, but to no avail.

I've also tried to export it as an xpi and install it in my main Firefox, but no dice there either

What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out that I didn't know hiding the panel I activate the handlers from wouldn't restore focus to the main window.

Doing `window.focus();` after activating the handlers fixed the issue.